# How to apply Hoare Logic to this function

Tags: logic, hoare-logic, software-verification

I would like to apply [Hoare Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic) to realistic, complex imperative programs that use while loops, if statements, functions, modules, etc. and have side effects (e.g. access the network). In order to get started with using Hoare Logic, I would like to see what it takes for this simple function:

```
function colorize(integer) {
  var hex = '#'

  if (integer > 1) hex += 'ff'
  else hex += '00'
  if (integer < 100) hex += 'aa'
  else hex += 'bb'
  if (integer > 10) hex += '11'
  else hex += '22'

  return hex
}
```

My first attempt so far is as follows. I haven't found a resource which describes how to model *functions* in the Hoare logic, so I just went off the cuff.

\begin{align}
\{hex = \# \land integer = y\}\\
if\ (integer > 1)\ hex += ff\\
\{hex = \#ff \land integer = y\}\\
\\
\{hex = \# \land integer = y\}\\ if\ \neg(integer > 1)\ hex += 00\\ \{hex = \#00 \land integer = y\}\\
\\
\{hex = \#\backslash{d}\backslash{d} \land integer = y\}\\ if\ (integer < 100)\ hex += aa\\ \{hex = \#\backslash{d}\backslash{daa} \land integer = y\}\\
\\
\{hex = \#\backslash{d}\backslash{d} \land integer = y\}\\if\ \neg(integer < 100)\ hex += bb\\ \{hex = \#\backslash{d}\backslash{dbb} \land integer = y\}\\
\\
\{hex = \#\backslash{d}\backslash{d} \land integer = y\}\\ if\ (integer > 10)\ hex += 11\\ \{hex = \#\backslash{d}\backslash{d}\backslash{d}\backslash{d11} \land integer = y\}\\
\\
\{hex = \#\backslash{d}\backslash{d} \land integer = y\}\\ if\ \neg(integer > 10)\ hex += 22\\ \{hex = \#\backslash{d}\backslash{d}\backslash{d}\backslash{d22} \land integer = y\}\\
\\
\{hex = \#\backslash{d}\backslash{d}\backslash{d}\backslash{d}\backslash{d}\backslash{d}\}\\ return\ hex\\ \{?\}\\
\\
\{x\}\\ x := colorize(y)\\ \{x = \#\backslash{d}\backslash{d}\backslash{d}\backslash{d}\backslash{d}\backslash{d} \}\\
\\
\{x\}\\ x := length(colorize(y))\\ \{x = 7\}
\end{align}

Then the question is, if we need to show explicit examples:

$$\{x\}\ x := colorize(0)\ \{x = \#00aa22\}$$

That wouldn't really make sense because then that's unit testing rather than *proving*.

Finally, the question is, how to *prove* that `colorize` returns the correct outputs.

What I don't understand about Hoare Logic so far is:

1. How to model functions. How to model the "variables are in a certain scope" of the function, as well as calling the function.
2. Which variables to include in the pre- and post-conditions in the example.
3. My understanding is these are *Hoare triples* (assertions). Are these considered *rules* or are they different than rules. If they aren't rules, wondering if I need to be creating rules as well somehow. Also not sure what I should be including in the Hoare Triples, if I was too-specific.
4. I saw stuff about partial vs. total correctness. Wondering if I need to somewhere include a proof of termination somehow, or each of these statements.
5. How to write a **proof**, given these (or the right) Hoare triples.
6. How to handle the "patterns" in the hex string. I just used regular expression digit format $\backslash d$.
7. What counts as a "program" (the middle part of the Hoare Triple). If `if (integer > 1) s` is one, or does it need to be broken down to the program `integer > 1`, or is that not a program.

I can follow the explanations of Hoare Triples in introductory presentations, but I am thinking I am a long way from applying it correctly. Looking for help to get over the initial starting complexity, would be helpful to show the specific Hoare Logic statements to define/prove this function, or some of them, so I can build on it.

Comment: Just saw the [hoare tableaux](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszvc/g52doa/hoare_tableaux.pdf) which seems like the way proofs are supposed to be written, not sure.